# Pass values to function further down the call stack

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

As my topic says, I want to know a method to send a value to a function which is called by another function. For example:

```
int main(){
 int sendingvalue=funtionreturningvalue();
 int x=0;
 function1(x);
}

function1(int x){
 //some code here 
 function2(x);
}

function2(int y){
 //again some code here
  function3();
}
function3(){
 //here I need the top value sendingvalue
}
```

It is so useless to explicitly pass that `int sendingvalue` again and again in all the functions until it reaches `function3`. So what is the best option to pass this value?

Comment: You either have to, like you said, pass it to each function or make it a global variable that any function can access.

Comment: Write it to a file, and then let the inner function read it back.

Comment: @2501 That's effectively a global variable.

Comment: @bejado yeh global it is

Comment: @2501 writing file make my prog more complex,so using global var

Comment: @namila007 Actually a global variable has infinitely more complexity.

Comment: @2501 what type of complexity? memory allocating issues?

Comment: @namila007 Productivity and safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options. You either make it a global variable, or you pass it through each function.

To make it a global variable, add the following line outside all of your function definitions:

```
int sendingvalue;
```

Then you access modify and read it from any function. If you don't want to use a global variable, you'll have to pass it along the stack.

Comment: thanks for replying, yeh creating a global var is the best thing so far

Comment: @namila007: There are very few use-cases where a global variable it "*the best thing*".

Comment: @alk What exactly is so bad about global variables?

Comment: @bace1000 Someone over on SoftwareEngineering.se wondered that same thing [a few years ago](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). They got quite a few responses.