# How to make a piece of data available for other functions further down the call stack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

For some specific Logging requirement, I would like to generate a variable, maybe an GUID that let me identify that function.
Then, I would like to access that variable in another function down the callstack **without modifying the function signature** of the original functions in the call stack

Is it possible or does It make sense?

> For context :
>
> I am generating some logs that I would like to "link" the caller to
> the function being called down the stream. In the caller, I am able to
> write some logs or assign some specific ID to the current function.
> However, down the callstack, It seems like im possible to access any
> information from the "Caller" apart from basic informations using StackTrace
>
> Lets imagine I have a some call chains like this
>
> A()
>
> => B()
>
> =>  => C()
>
> How would I know that the current instance of C() is being invoked by the specific A() call without passing the A() 's GUID down the call stack to B() and then to C() ?

I made some research but the result seems old that does not necessarily match the current situation anymore
[Pass values to function further down the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448587/pass-values-to-function-further-down-the-call-stack)

Comment: Why can you not just use a field/property of the containing class for the functions to store the data?

Comment: NLog lets you do this using the Mapped Diagnostic Logical Context.  I think you can use [`System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext?view=netframework-4.8), maybe, but this is tagged .Net Core, which I'm less familiar with.

Comment: Create a GUID property at the class level

Comment: Do you need to access it or is it just for logs as it sounds like you want [log scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-scopes)

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman Thank you for the input. I am looking for a solution that require less change in the class. And I am not sure that would be suitable for static functions plus the class-level GUID would be shared between different function invocations on the same "object"?

Do you all think the requirement I have at the moment make sense/ Is this an interesting case?

Comment: Thanks, @George I have already utilized the log scopes in my code. Unfortunately, the one in question is a more simple different logging mechanism ( In fact, It is the AWS X Ray API ). It would be great however if I can "Get the current scope" from the logger as I included the NLog logger in every layers of my code. Then I can pass that information to X Ray. Do you think It is possible?

Comment: @qkhanhpro it should be possible, you could potentially look at [this interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iexternalscopeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and see if it does what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at available solution, seems like this is a widely used feature. For NET Standard, `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext` is used

> Provides a set of properties that are carried with the execution code path.

For .NET Core, `System.Threading.AsyncLocal<T>` is available

> Represents ambient data that is local to a given asynchronous control
>   flow, such as an asynchronous method.

A full implementation can be seen in [this blog](http://www.cazzulino.com/callcontext-netstandard-netcore.html)

One can also take inspiration from NLog's [NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/10d1bdc48ce44cd5b845e4b216d3716523970b72/src/NLog/Contexts/NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.cs) which seems to utilize both mentioned solutions for a comprehensive message passing mechanism inside logical scope

Answer (score 0):

Well … as a comment: you are trying to do something that is not meant to be done. That is, you want to hand a value to called functions but not by the normal method of using a parameter that gets pushed onto the successive stack frames.

I won't pass judgement on that but it does point towards a possible solution: you could recreate the function call stack mechanism within your code. In other words have a Stack global variable and in each method push the method method name and GUID onto the stack. Then in your example method C you can walk the stack to find the GUID of the calling instance of A. Assuming you are working in a multi-tasking environment you may also want to push the current Task id and/or have separate stacks for each thread or each task.

As you pointed out StackTrace.GetFrame(i) already does this kind of thing, but it only provides rudimentary information such as the name of the method. However that could still be sufficient, depending on your situation. For example you could walk all the way down to the bottom of the stack trace to find out all the active instances of A and where they were called from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sure what I am trying to do is very not normal. The answer gives me some interesting idea...

Comment: Will this work with tasks as well?